# Renaming files with python results in duplicate files

Tags: python-3.x

I have a folder with the following files:

- [11111]Text.txt
- [22222]Text.txt
- [33333]Text.txt
- [44444]Text.txt

I need rename the files to remove the [11111] designation from the beginning of the file name, however that results in duplicate file names.

I wrote a basic script out that will strip the [11111] from the first file, and if any duplication occurs with subsequent files it will name the file **[Duplicate]_[#]_text.txt** where **[#]** is a random number

When I ran the code, it renamed the first file correctly, and renamed the second file with the required string, but it did not continue with the other files, and instead presented the following error:

**FileExistsError: [WinError 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists: 'Destination/[33333]Text.txt' -> 'Destination/[Duplicate]_[1]Text.txt'**

The code below is what I have currently, though i have tried several iterations also

```
Location = (Destination_Folder)

Dupe_Counter = random.randint(0,255)

for filename in os.listdir(Location):
    try:
        if filename.startswith("["):
            os.rename(Location + filename, Location + filename[7:])
    except:
            os.rename(Location + filename, Location +'[Duplicate]_' + '[' + str(Dupe_Counter) +']' + filename[7:])
```

I'm assuming that it's not actually picking up the Dupe_Counter when creating new files, however I'm not 100% sure where i'm going wrong.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Dupe_Counter you are generating a random number that can collide with the results sometimes. But on top of that, you are generating the random Dupe_Counter once only.
Try to generate a random number for each iteration.

```
Location = (Destination_Folder)

for filename in os.listdir(Location):
    Dupe_Counter = random.randint(0,255)
    try:
        if filename.startswith("["):
            os.rename(Location + filename, Location + filename[7:])
    except:
            os.rename(Location + filename, Location +'[Duplicate]_' + '[' + str(Dupe_Counter) +']' + filename[7:])
```

But I would recommend generating an increasing sequence for renaming the files and better understanding.
Something Like this:

```
Location = (Destination_Folder)

for filename in os.listdir(Location):
    Dupe_Counter = 101
    try:
        if filename.startswith("["):
            os.rename(Location + filename, Location + filename[7:])
    except:
            os.rename(Location + filename, Location +'[Duplicate]_' + '[' + str(Dupe_Counter) +']' + filename[7:])
            Dupe_Counter += 1
```

Hope I've been of some help.